# Find maximum volume of a box using AM-GM inequality

Tags: contest-math, volume, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Raphael has a art sheet of $2m$ by $3m$. In order to frame an open box, he cuts four equal squares from the corners of the sheet, folds it along the cuts and glues the lateral faces of the box along their common edges. If the box is to have the largest possible volume, what should be the length of the sides of the squares he cut ?

My work :

Framing equations,

The height = $x$ m 
The length = $(3 - 2x)$ m 
The width = $(2 - 2x)$ m

Applying AM-GM inequality gives:

$$(2-2 x)(3-2 x) x \leq\left(\frac{(2-2 x)+(3-2 x)+x}{3}\right)^{3}$$

Now, RHS has a dependency on $x$.
Here is where I am stuck, how to proceed further ? *The book instructs to not use derivatives.*

Possible duplicate with the same technique: [here, however it uses derivatives and the 1st answer doesn't answer my case.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2866602/possible-mistake-finding-the-maximum-volume-of-a-box-with-the-am-gm-inequality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
In such cases, you should consider taking the means for $3-2x, \alpha(2-2x), \beta x$ (assuming you got those terms correctly), for suitable coefficients $\alpha, \beta$.

These unknown coefficients can be chosen to meet the following desirable conditions to use AM-GM inequality:
(a) The sum of the terms should be a constant. i.e. $-2-2\alpha + \beta = 0$
(b) Equality is possible.  i.e. there is an allowable value of $x$. s.t. $3-2x=\alpha(2-2x)=\beta x > 0$.

Solving these, you should get $x = \frac16(5-\sqrt7)$.

--
P.S. of course derivative approach would also give you the same $x$.

Comment: > (a) The sum of the terms should be a constant. i.e. −2−2α+β=0.

Mind explaining why so ? and the "terms" here refer to the exact combination of -2 -2α+β = 0 ? (better question: Where does these terms come from ?).

I wasn't aware of this technique either, any references how/why this works ?

Comment: You're attempting to create an upper bound for the volume using GM $\le$ AM.  Now that upper bound should be a constant, which can be actually achieved (i.e. the terms you are applying AM-GM must add to a real number, be positive and equal at some point.)

Comment: Totally understand the logic now. But I still want to clarify further where does "−2−2α+β=0" come from?

Comment: In the sum of terms, coefficient of $x$ must vanish as the sum needs to be a constant (we need a real number upper bound). That gives the first condition.

Comment: Ohhhh, I see. Thanks ! clarified fully.